# Using Infopath without SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, infopath

One of my clients need to use an infopath form to obtain information from the users and submit it to a database. But he doesn't have SharePoint. So I want to know if there is any way that we can use Infopath just only as a form to fill data and send that data to a database.

And also is there anyway that we can view that form in a browser? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

InfoPath includes a Form Template that can feed directly into a database. It can also publish the results to XML files, one per response. I think SP is required for the web forms functionality, but InfoPath filler can be used to fill the forms but not change them.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can have a form submit to a database or a folder in exchange. The advantage sharepoint brings is that data analysis on the form results is much easier. You can create forms using Infopath and Visual Studio has templates but they do not seem intuitive. Check out the videos on youtube by lynda.com they give a good overview of what is possible with infopath.